# How can i encrypt data before i pass to aspx page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, encryption, asp-classic

I have an application, it lands on asp page, which has a html menu like this,

```
  <ul class="clearfix">
      <li [customers] ><a class="nav-icon icon-book_addresses" href="customer.asp">Customers</a></li>      
      <li [payments] ><a class="nav-icon icon-housego" href="payments.asp">Payments</a></li>      
      <li [suspended] ><a class="nav-icon icon-email" href="../take[site]/suspended?CompanyID=[CompanyID]&LoginName=[LoginName]">Suspend List</a></li>
      <li [wages] ><a class="nav-icon icon-email" href="../take[site]/wages?CompanyID=[CompanyID]&LoginName=[LoginName]">Wages</a></li>      
    </ul>
```

And the request goes in the url as this to the aspx page.

wages/?CompanyID=1&LoginName=Admin

How can i encrypt the data before sending to the aspx page? Using a javascript in this html page can be done? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Why not running your website on https (ssl)? That way the whole web-communication is encrypted without any effort (from your side). If you need help with that, let me know.